# Detach and attach partition db2 version 10.5 giving sqlstate 55007 error

Tags: sql, db2, partitioning, detach

I have a db2 procedure which detaches a partition into temp table and then attaches back the partition. When I execute the detach, drop and attach from rapid sql it works perfectly fine but when I execute it from the stored procedure I see this error.

The object "udbadm.table_name"  of type table cannot be altered because it is currently in use by the same application process. Please advice. Below is my stored procedure.

Edited the code to include dbms_alert.sleep(120); Seeing the error A null value was specified in a context where null value is not allowed.sqlstate 22004

db2 version is 10.5. I am executing this from rapid sql but when invoked from line processor as db2 => call OSL_CLNUP_MNTHLY_SBLDGR_DET(98,56,'08/31/2018',5) I received same error.

```
DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE OSLD02.OSL_CLNUP_MNTHLY_SBLDGR_DET
;
  CREATE PROCEDURE OSLD02.OSL_CLNUP_MNTHLY_SBLDGR_DET(IN    
                                          IN_ID_BUS_PROCSS SMALLINT,
                                                IN IN_ID_RUN SMALLINT,
                                                IN IN_DT_EOP DATE,
                                                IN IN_BATCH_SIZE INTEGER)
SPECIFIC OSLD02.OSL_CLNUP_MNTHLY_SBLDGR_DET
MODIFIES SQL DATA
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NULL CALL
LANGUAGE SQL EXTERNAL ACTION
INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS

 BEGIN

--------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------
-------------------- Declarations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------   ---------------------------------------
declare v_id_task_log    integer;
declare v_cnt_deleted    integer;
declare v_cnt_initial    integer;
declare v_count integer;
declare v_cd_acctg_purp character(10);
declare v_month_eop integer;
declare SQLCODE int default 0; 
declare v_sqlcode int;
declare v_partitionName character(20);
declare v_lowValue character(10);
declare v_highValue character(10);
declare v_detachStmt varchar(512);    
declare v_dropTable varchar(512);   
declare SQL_STMT varchar(512);   
declare v_exist int;
declare v_stagingSchemaTable varchar(512);
DECLARE v_outmessage VARCHAR(32672);
 DECLARE v_outstatus integer default 0;
 DECLARE v_seconds INTEGER default 300;
 declare wait_until timestamp;
declare detach_complete_flg character(2) default 'N';
declare loop_limit int default 0;

declare global temporary table session.detail_tmp
( partition character(10), start character(30), end character(30) ) on    
  commit preserve rows with replace not logged;

 BEGIN

 DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
 select   DATAPARTITIONNAME, LOWVALUE, HIGHVALUE
 from syscat.DATAPARTITIONS  where tabname='SBLDGR_DET'
 and  (SUBSTR(HIGHVALUE, 2,LOCATE(',',HIGHVALUE)-3)
,SUBSTR(HIGHVALUE, LOCATE(',',HIGHVALUE)+1) ) in (
 select  CD_ACCTG_PURP, mo_eop
 from SBLDGR_DET
 where mo_eop< cast (month(IN_DT_EOP) as char(2))
 group by CD_ACCTG_PURP, mo_eop
 having count(*)>0
 )
with ur;

OPEN C1;--
set v_sqlcode=0;--

L1: LOOP
 FETCH C1 INTO v_partitionName, v_lowValue,v_highValue;
 IF SQLCODE<> 0 THEN 
 LEAVE L1; 
 END IF;

set v_detachStmt = 'ALTER TABLE SBLDGR_DET DETACH PARTITION '   
 ||v_partitionName|| ' INTO TABLE OSLSTG.SL_DET_'||v_partitionName;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_detachStmt ;
 commit;


 while (loop_limit < 10000 and detach_complete_flg = 'N') DO
call dbms_alert.sleep(60);

 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS WHERE TABSCHEMA='OSLSTG'
     AND 
         TABNAME='SL_DET_'|| v_partitionName AND STATUS=' ')    
THEN             
 set detach_complete_flg = 'Y'; 
 END IF; 

 set loop_limit = loop_limit + 1;
 end while;

 set v_dropTable = 'drop table OSLSTG.SL_DET_'||v_partitionName; 
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dropTable ;
commit;

 SET SQL_STMT   = 'ALTER TABLE sbldgr_det ADD    
PARTITION '||v_partitionName||' STARTING FROM (' || v_lowValue|| ' )
ENDING AT (' || v_highValue|| ')';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL_STMT;   
commit;

END LOOP L1;

 CLOSE   C1;--

 END
 ;

END
;

commit;
```

Comment: You have to wait for the detach to complete (one part of it is async). Consider sleeping, periodically checking utility status.

Comment: Thanks Mao. In my procedure I have added to sleep but commented it out. How can I check for utility status. Any pointers that can you provide?

Comment: For sleeping use either DBMS_ALERT.SLEEP() (undocumented) or DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE (documented). For checking utility completion check MON_GET_UTILITY or query syscat.datapartitions. There's also  SNAP_GET_UTIL_PROGRESS().

Comment: Thanks Mao. I used dbms_alert.sleep(300) but when running the stored procedure I am getting null value specified in a context where its not allowed. sqlstate 22004 error.Can you please advice.

Comment: Updated the code to include sleep method. I am trying to look at example how to implement utility completion using the methods you implemented, but unable to figure out what we need to check using these functions. Please help with any pointers or examples.

Comment: Updated the question Mao. I just tried dbms_alert.waitone('whatever', v_outmessage,v_outstatus, v_Seconds); v_seconds as 300; and I got the same error that I received as using sleep method.

Comment: Mao, Can you please provide any sample reference code for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of problems in your code. I'm not going to provide you a complete solution, just some notes.

1) If you `commit` during a cursor processing, you must [DECLARE CURSOR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html) with the `WITH HOLD` clause.

2) The following cursor processing is not correct.

```
WHILE (v_sqlcode = 0) DO
  FETCH C1 INTO v_partitionName, v_lowValue,v_highValue;
  set v_sqlcode=sqlcode;
  set v_detachStmt = 'ALTER TABLE SBLDGR_DET DETACH PARTITION'
    ||v_partitionName||' INTO TABLE OSLSTG.SL_DET_'||v_partitionName;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_detachStmt;
  ...
END WHILE;
```

You still try to process data even you got the `END OF CURSOR` code after `FETCH`.
You must check `SQLCODE` immediately after `FETCH`. Use something like this:

```
L1: LOOP
  FETCH C1 INTO v_partitionName, v_lowValue,v_highValue;
  IF SQLCODE<>0 THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
  ...
END LOOP L1;
```

3) You should do something like below.

After:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_detachStmt;
commit;
```

You should implement:

```
-- Check in loop (sleep, let's say N sec, after each check) 
-- until you get a row with the following statement
-- (construct your table name dynamically):

SELECT 1 
FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='OSLSTG' AND TABNAME='SL_DET_v_partitionName' AND STATUS=''
WITH UR;
```

Look at the [Detaching data partitions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.partition.doc/doc/t0021576.html) topic for more detail.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your inputs. I will incorporate these and test it out.

Comment: Mark Appreciate all the inputs you provided. I made the changes as you had mentioned but the partition is not getting dropped. The return code of the program is zero but the partition data is not getting dropped; Can you please check and let me know if anything incorrect over here.

Comment: Insert debugging calls of `CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('msg: '||v_*);` into your code, and use the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` command before calling your routine in `DB2 CLP` to understand what happens. Or use debugger and inform us about what exactly happens inside the routine during its execution.